# Draw route between two coordination on google maps in Xcode

Tags: ios, json, xcode, google-maps, google-maps-sdk-ios

Actually I'm stuck in a simple problem for about two days.

I want to draw a route between my location and another location on Google maps.

I am using Google map sdk and I've read every question available on Stackoverflow but I had no chance achieving this.

I know I should send a request to some Google API and parse the json, but I don't know how to parse that json and then unseeing that data to draw route on map.

any link or piece of code appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

actually there is a way without using google sdk or googlemaps framework
take a webview and you have to call a url that is.....

```
if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:url]){
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://maps.google.com/maps/place/%@", location]]];
    [businessLocationWebView loadRequest:request];
}
```

then it will show the location you entered.
There u will see the view like this
[image: google maps page]

there u can find the route from your location to a specified location entered in the textfield

Happy coding